# How do I correctly use userData in Box2d?

Tags: c++, box2d

Many guides used userData. But with the source of Box2d I have, I don't see the `SetUserData` functions in the code as I see them in the guides.

After understanding it, I realized that these manuals were outdated, and
now there is no such function and userData should be set in a different way. After digging through the Box2d files for three days, I realized that I could not cope alone.

I found out that it is possible to edit the b2FixtureDef structure to add my new data there. But I don't understand how to do this correctly, because just adding a line to the structure of the program crashes.

This is what I want to do:

```
class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener
{
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) 
    {
        //check if fixture A was the foot sensor
        std::string fixtureUserData = contact->GetFixtureA()->getmy();
        if ((int)fixtureUserData == 3)
            fixturesUnderfoot.insert(contact->GetFixtureB());//A is foot so B is ground
        //check if fixture B was the foot sensor
        fixtureUserData = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetUserData();
        if ((int)fixtureUserData == 3)
            fixturesUnderfoot.insert(contact->GetFixtureA());//B is foot so A is ground
    }

    void EndContact(b2Contact* contact) 
    {
        //check if fixture A was the foot sensor
        void* fixtureUserData = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetUserData();
        if ((int)fixtureUserData == 3)
            fixturesUnderfoot.erase(contact->GetFixtureB());//A is foot so B is ground
        //check if fixture B was the foot sensor
        fixtureUserData = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetUserData();
        if ((int)fixtureUserData == 3)
            fixturesUnderfoot.erase(contact->GetFixtureA());//B is foot so A is ground
    }
};
```

previously, it was possible, as I understood, to create a body and write:

```
body.setUserData = smth;
body.getUserData();
```

but this is not possible because the method returns a structure:

```
b2BodyUserData& b2Body::GetUserData()
{
    return m_userData;
}

struct b2BodyUserData
{
    b2BodyUserData()
    {
        pointer = 0;
    }

    /// For legacy compatibility
    uintptr_t pointer;
};
```

next to the structure definition, it is written "You can define this to inject whatever data you want in b2Fixture".

When I did something like this, the program is crashing:

```
struct B2_API b2FixtureUserData
{
    b2FixtureUserData()
    {
        pointer = 0;
        objectType = "";
    }
    std::string objectType;
    /// For legacy compatibility
    uintptr_t pointer;
};
```

Comment: Hmm, [`b2Fixture`](https://box2d.org/documentation/classb2_fixture.html) does not have a `getmy` function, shouldn't it be `GetUserData`? Also, how do you set this user data?

Comment: i set it like :
b2FixtureDef boxFDef;
boxFDef.userData.objectType = "box";
and then the program crashes with this code -1073741819.

Comment: @Vaillancourt,
I didn't finish it once and forgot it. I apologize.
reading data should look like this, right?
std::string fixtureUserData = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetUserData().objectType;
where objectType its my new data;

Comment: Before I spend too much time on this, I just want to make sure you've read [this part of the official documentation](https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_loose_ends.html#autotoc_md121).

Comment: @Vaillancourt, I spent three days searching for this information in other parts of this manual. Thank u so much

Comment: I agree, it should be placed in a more obvious/useful location.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that box2d [recently changed the way they manage userData](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d/commit/f0f9d50a328a709cc3a287a61b864e7d0e3ef35f). They went from storing `void` pointers to storing an actual object. So it may explain why you see tutorials around that "do no work" with a more recent version of Box2d.

[This part of the official documentation](https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_loose_ends.html#autotoc_md121) illustrates how this should be done now, however it lacks an important information, IMHO.

The user data is an object that *you* control and you *need hold alive for the whole life of the box2d object*.

Since the userData deals with "opaque pointers" (Box2d does not know what those are nor what they're for, only you do), and the example uses raw pointers, Box2d will *not* clean the memory associated to those once the Box2d objects are destroyed, *you* need to take care of cleaning those.

A way to do it is to wrap those into smart pointers.

So somewhere in your code you need to create your own class:

```
struct MyFixtureUserDataType
{
    int mObjectType {};
    b2Fixture* mOwningFixture {};
}
```

Then when you create your fixtures, you also create the data:

```
// Store this somewhere in your game managing classes
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyFixtureUserDataType>> mFixtureUserData;

// Create your userData object
auto myUserData = std::make_unique<MyFixtureUserDataType>();
myUserData->mObjectType = 3; // whatever this fixture is about

// create the def
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.userData.pointer = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(myUserData.get());

// create your fixture
myUserData->mOwningFixture = body->CreateFixture( fixtureDef );

// Now you store you data
mFixtureUserData.emplace_back( std::move(myUserData) );
myUserData = nullptr;
```

Then when you destroy the fixture, you can remove the associated instance of MyFixtureUserDataType.

```
b2Fixture* myFixtureToDestroy = ....;

body->DestroyFixture(myFixtureToDestroy);

for ( int i = 0; i < mFixtureUserData.size(); ++i )
{
  if( mFixtureUserData[i]->mOwningFixture == myFixtureToDestroy )
  {
    std::swap( mFixtureUserData[i], mFixtureUserData[mFixtureUserData.size() - 1] );
    mFixtureUserData.pop_back();
    break;
  }
}
```

This is a trivial example; mFixtureUserData could also be an `std::map<[fixture pointer], std::unique_ptr<MyFixtureUserDataType>>` to allow faster search.

But you get the gist of it, the idea is to keep track of your user data in some way an make sure you clean it when you destroy the associated Box2d objects.

I've created a small complete-ish example [here on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7765d15fe603a3d9) of this workflow.